# How to use getActivity() without returning NULL in other functions?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How do I use `getActivity` or `activity` in other functions outside of `onCreate View`, when I use activity in oncreateview or other functions it returns *null.* in a fragment.

Is there a way to store `activity` and use it as a variable in a function outside of oncreateview?

There are answers for this in java but I couldn't find in Kotlin, (interchanging between them is a bit confusing)

This is onCreateView

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        var mActivity = activity. // This returned Null

        phRecycler = view?.findViewById(R.id.recyle)
        E_shelf = view?.findViewById(R.id.E_shelf)
        phoneRecycler()

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home3, container, false)
    }
```

this is another function in the same fragment

```
 fun phoneRecycler() {

        //All Gradients
        //HSSFSheet sheet = readExcel();
        val TAG = "Main"
        val myMap: MutableMap<String, Int> = HashMap()
        myMap["Index"] = 0
        val LatestShelf = ArrayList<phonehelper>()
        val exs = ArrayList<phonehelper>()
        phoneRecycler!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(Activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false).   // activity returns null
...
```

> **I am getting Null value for `activity` wherever I put it, even in the OnCreateView, also this fragment is connected to a xml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I would suggest you to put

```
 phRecycler = view?.findViewById(R.id.recyle)
        E_shelf = view?.findViewById(R.id.E_shelf)
        phoneRecycler()
```

inside onViewCreated() method.

Also, your answer is Simple, use

```
/**
*as Per Docs, for requireActivity(), "Return the FragmentActivity this fragment is currently associated with."
*/
this.requireActivity()
// or simply
requireActivity()

/**
* another method would be 
* as per docs, for activity or getActivity(), "Return the FragmentActivity this fragment is currently associated with. May return null if the fragment is associated with a Context instead."
*/

val activity = this.activity
if(activity== null) throw error()
```

**EDIT:**
Please Try This Code

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home3, container, false)
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    E_shelf = view.findViewById(R.id.E_shelf)
    phoneRecycler()

}

fun phoneRecycler() {

    //All Gradients
    //HSSFSheet sheet = readExcel();
    val TAG = "Main"
    val myMap: MutableMap<String, Int> = HashMap()
    myMap["Index"] = 0
    val LatestShelf = ArrayList<phonehelper>()
    val exs = ArrayList<phonehelper>()
    
    //remove any other variable declartion
    val phoneRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recyle)
    phoneRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false).   // activity returns null
    ...
```

Comment: `requireActivity` will throw an error if you try to use it when the fragment is not attached to an activity

Comment: okay then, I'll edit my answer and include more info.

Comment: I tried this, but I still get Null when using it inside oncreateview

Comment: press ```ctrl+o``` if using windows, a pop-up will appear and search for onViewCreated and try using it inside that method instead of onCreateView.

Comment: if your error still persists, paste your error in comment

Comment: I searched for onViewCreated but there seems to be no function

Comment: and also I'm not sure how exactly to override the onviewcreate function

Comment: okay copy and paste this ```override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235347/discussion-between-lets-start-coding-and-maketheerrordie).

Answer (score 1):

If a fragment is no longer attached to an activity then the `activity` variable is going to be null

you need to null check each time you try to use it

Comment: but it seems to always return null wherever I put it

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your situation would be nice to replace logic from `OnCreateView` to `OnActivityCreated` method. Cause in this method getActivity != null always.

Comment: OnActivityCreated is deprecated rather use onViewCreated